# Getting error with exp, sin, cos functions in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

b = tf.constant(2)

**sess.run(tf.exp(b))**
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Exp' with these attrs**
     [[Node: Exp = Exp[T=DT_INT32](Const_1)]]
Caused by op u'Exp', defined at:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 505, in exp
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Exp", x=x, name=name)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/aravindp/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

>>>
```

Comment: It is extremely clear, everything you are trying to do and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

b = tf.constant(2.)
sess = tf.Session()
print (sess.run(tf.exp(b)))
```

Comment: For somehow, dtype=int32, and dtype=int64 give the error. The API doc says, "x: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: float32, float64, int32, complex64, int64". I'm reading the source code.

Comment: Thank you, float types are working fine but as you mentioned the API docs do say it supports int32 and int64.
same error with the log, sin and cos Ops too for dtype int32 and int64

Comment: @AravindPilla I'm looking into the issue. Thanks for asking this.

Comment: There was a similar issue of "Prod" not being defined for int32, this fix was pretty simple if you want to dig into it -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b874e2ccfda77c964bfb0a41a8dc339e320b185c

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks to your hint, I sent a PR, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2227. Could you comment on it? Thanks!